# Convergence of subsequence. Equivalent definitions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in metric space $(X,d)$ and its subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ converges to $a\in X$.

I want to show that the following are equivalent:

**i)** $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists N$ : $\forall k>N$ $\Rightarrow$ $d(x_{n_k},a)<\epsilon$.

**ii)** $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists N$ : $\forall n_k>N$ $\Rightarrow$ $d(x_{n_k},a)<\epsilon$.

I was able to show that **ii)** $\Rightarrow$ **i)**

Indeed, take arbitrary $\epsilon >0$  then by part **ii)** $\exists N$ : $\forall n_k>N$ $\Rightarrow$ $d(x_{n_k},a)<\epsilon$. But if $k>N$ and taking into account that $n_k>k$ we will get that $d(x_{n_k},a)<\epsilon$.

However I cannot show the converse direction. So I would be very grateful if anyone can help to me, please?

Here is my approach for **i)** $\Rightarrow$ **ii)** Take arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ then by part **i)** $\exists N$ : $\forall k>N$ $\Rightarrow$ $d(x_{n_k},a)<\epsilon$. But if $n_k>N$ then we will get $$d(x_{n_{n_k}},a)<\epsilon,$$

i.e. the last inequality has double index which really bothers me.

Comment: Hint: The map $k \mapsto n_k$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @copper.hat, As you see i have used it in direction ii) $\Rightarrow$ i). But i do not know how to use it in converse however i was thinking about this.

Comment: @copper.hat, so my inequality with double lower index is right? You mean that I have to apply your hint to it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose using (i) you have found $N$. Then for **any** $k > N$ the right hand side holds.

Note that $k \mapsto n_k$ is strictly increasing. Hence if $n_k > n_N$, we must have $k > N$. So, pick $n_N$ for (ii).

Comment: To be honest i did not get your second line of the argument: you have to show that if $n_k>N$ then $d(x_{n_k},a)<\epsilon$.

Comment: The $N$ in (ii) does not have to be the same $N$ in (i). (i) shows that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $N$ such that if $k > N$ then then right hand side holds. Hence for the same $\epsilon$, if we choose $n_k > n_N$ (and hence $k >N$) then the right hand side holds.

Comment: This really makes sense! thanks a lot! +1. I'll accept your answer

Comment: @ZFR: Good luck!